# What does --enable-profiling option do when compiling Python?

Tags: python

I'm buildinng my own Python-2.6 in linux. There's an option in configure for enabling C-level code profiling. I've never used that before; so just out of curiousity, what does that option do? what is it for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google tells me this:

> Python can now be built with
> additional profiling for the
> interpreter itself, intended as an aid
> to people developing the Python core.
> Providing
> ---enable-profiling to the configure script will let you profile the
> interpreter with gprof

If you are unfamiliar with `gprof`, have a look at this [link](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gprof-2.9.1/html_mono/gprof.html)

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you. Plus points up for googling skills that I was lazy enough not to put in use.